# Microsoft Debug-File Server/Service

Tags: visual-studio, windbg

1. Does the debug service keep files up-to-date, with respect to security patches?
2. Generally, what's the turn-around time between the release of an update and the corresponding PDBs on the debug service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the Microsoft Symbol Server, then:

1. Yes. Security (and other) patches are available on the symbol server. Hotfixes where you have to get them from PSS (support) may not be.
2. Patches appear fairly quickly. I think they're actually pushed out as part of Microsoft's build/release process. Release candidates and CTPs don't always appear immediately (Windows 7 RC didn't, but the symbol package was separately downloadable via Connect).

Comment: I think that QFE won't appear in the debug symbols, as for the rest they will be on the symbols server even before the official release.